# int.TryParse() returns false for "#.##"

Tags: c#, tryparse

I'm having a function which receives string parameters and convert them to integers. 
For safe conversion int.TryParse() is used.

```
public IEnumerable<object> ReportView(string param1, string param2)
{
  int storeId = int.TryParse(param1, out storeId) ? storeId : 0;
  int titleId = int.TryParse(param2, out titleId) ? titleId : 0;
  IEnumerable<object> detailView = new Report().GetData(storeId, titleId);
  return detailView;
}
```

Function call ReportView(“2”,”4”)--> int.Tryparse successfully parsing the numbers 
Function call ReportView(“2.00”,”4.00”) --> int.TryParse fails to parse the numbers

Why? Any idea?

**@Update**
Sorry guys, my concept was wrong. I'm new to c#, I thought Int.TryParse() would return integral part and ignore the decimals. But it won't, even Convert.ToInt32("string") 
Thanks to all.

Comment: You should also specify a culture.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. The question is clearly a beginners question, but it is clear, and reasonably well formulated.

Comment: @moguzalp Should people get downvoted for not knowing something when they ask a question?

Comment: @moguzalp: I bet equivalent parsing code would work in many languages. I am very glad it does not in work like that in C#... But it is not as self evident to a newcomer as it might seem to you or me.

Comment: While writing this code, I thought int.TryParse would return the integral part and ignore the decimals. Thanks guys, it was a blunder.

Comment: @Henk Holterman,@CodeInChaos,@jdv-Jan de Vaan,@moguzalp,@Eric Dahlvang Thanks friends, Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<object> ReportView(string param1, string param2)
{
  decimal tmp;
  int storeId = decimal.TryParse(param1, out tmp) ? (int)tmp : 0;
  int titleId = decimal.TryParse(param2, out tmp) ? (int)tmp : 0;
  IEnumerable<object> detailView = new Report().GetData(storeId, titleId);
  return detailView;
}
```

The above will work with Integer or Decimal strings. Mind you that strings of the form "2.123" will result in the Integer value of 2 being returned.

Answer (score 8):

int.TryParse will not try to parse the string and convert it to an integer just in case. You need to use decimal.TryParse for a decimal number string.

Answer (score 5):

2.00 and 4.00 aren't integers; they're decimal values that just happen to have 0's after the decimal point. If you want to parse decimals, use decimal.TryParse() or double.TryParse(), and then truncate them or check for a zero-value mantissa.

Answer (score 5):

To a computer "2.00" is a float/decimal, not an integer.  Instead of doing decimal.TryParse() you can pre-process the string by removing the trailing zeros and then do int.TryParse().  So if you have "2.00", you keep checking (and dropping) the last character of the string until you reach the "." (decimal).  If it is "0" or "." you can drop it.  In the end you will end up with just "2".

Answer (score 3):

2.00 and 4.00 are not of Integer data types - that's why. If you want those to be true try, double.TryParse() or decimal.TryParse()

Answer (score 2):

It fails to parse because decimal numbers are not integers.

Answer (score 2):

well 2.00 is a decimal number, not an int in a computers eyes.

Answer (score 2):

An Int32 (int) can only contain integral values; therefore the Int32 Parse/TryParse functions cannot parse strings with decimals. If your string values might contain decimals but are intended to represent integers, use Decimal.TryParse and then cast.

Answer (score 1):

Because "2.00" is a decimal, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to provide a 'catch all' solution:

```
if (IntegerObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntegerObject.ToString()))
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    if (int.TryParse(IntegerObject.ToString(), out int integerValue))
    {
        return integerValue;
    }
    else
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(IntegerObject.ToString(), out decimal decimalValue))
        {
            return (int)Math.Round(decimalValue, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**.